# Add blank screen into video grid

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to do a 9 videos grid using FFMPEG, but the last one must be blank.

|  Video 1  |  Video 2  |  Video 3  |

|  Video 4  |  Video 5  |  Video 6  |

|  Video 7  |  Video 8  |  No video |

So far, I got this:

```
ffmpeg  -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 \
    -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 -i video6.mp4 \
    -i video7.mp4 -i video8.mp4 -i video9.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=3[h1]; \
             [3:v][4:v][5:v]hstack=3[h2]; \
             [6:v][7:v][8:v]hstack=3[h3]; \
             [h1][h2][h3]vstack=3[v]"  \
-map "[v]" mosaic.mp4
```

which produced a perfect grid with 9 videos.

The next step is remove the last one and add a blank screen with "No video" written.

I saw at [this link](https://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-December/029493.html) someone saying to use

```
-f lavfi -i color=s=WxH:color=black
```

but I don't know how (or where) to use it...

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg  -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 \
    -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 -i video6.mp4 \
    -i video7.mp4 -i video8.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=s=WxH \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=3[h1]; \
             [3:v][4:v][5:v]hstack=3[h2]; \
             [8]drawtext=text='No video':fontfile=/path/to/fontfile:fontsize=20:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:fontcolor=white[bl];
             [6:v][7:v][bl]hstack=3:shortest=1[h3]; \
             [h1][h2][h3]vstack=3[v]"  \
-map "[v]" mosaic.mp4
```

Comment: Mulvya, I tried your code, but I got this error:

    Unable to parse option value "WxH" as image size
        Last message repeated 1 times
    Error setting option s to value WxH.
    Error applying options to the filter.
    Error initializing filter 'color' with args 's=WxH'
color=s=WxH: Invalid argument

So I tried change the "WxH" for "352x240" and the error was solved, but the process never finishes, i.e., these values keep increasing indefinately:

    frame= 1463 fps=9.8 q=20.0 size=   54402kB time=00:11:45.00 bitrate= 632.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=17087 speed=4.71x

Comment: WxH is a placeholder, not to be used literally. Corrected command for termination.

Comment: Now I could generate the mosaic without the text! When I try to add it, I get this error:

[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 00000000027a3240] Option 'color' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002727d20] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'text=No video:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=20:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:color=white'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found

P.S.: I copied the font to my folder.